# How can i manipulate DOM inside the onScroll event in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am trying to creating an arrow-up button, which will be set to `display: "none"` if I am at a top of my page, and when I scroll down further, I want to set it to display: "block". How can i achieve this? I am trying to manipulate the DOM inside my handleScroll function but it doesn't work.

My TopButton.js component

```
import React from "react";
import "../assets/arrow-up.png";

class TopButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  };

  handleScroll = () => {
    console.log("scroll");

    let x = document.getElementsByClassName("topbutton_button");
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("topbutton_button");
    // x.style.display = "none";

    // console.log(event.target.className);

    // if (
    //   document.body.scrollTop > 40 ||
    //   document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40
    // ) {
    //   style.display = "block";
    // } else {
    //   display = "none";
    // }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="topbutton_container">
        <button
          style={{ display: "block" }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          className="topbutton_button"
        >
          <img src={require("../assets/arrow-up.png")} />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TopButton;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two reasons it didn't work:

- See [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method); basically, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element, but your commented-out code was treating it as though it were a single element.
- If your component was ever re-rendered, it would be rendered in its default state, not the updated state you changed via the DOM

But that's not how you'd do it with React. Instead, you'd:

1. have the button state (whether it should be block or not) held as state in your component;
2. use that state when rendering the `topbutton_button`, setting its style or class accordingly; and
3. update that state in your `handleScroll` handler

A couple of others notes:

- You also need to remove your handler when the component is unmounting
- You shouldn't use arrow functions for component lifecycle functions
- You don't need to use `bind` on an arrow function (`handleScroll` for instance). *Either* make it an arrow function *or* use `bind` in the constructor to bind it.

Something along these lines, see the `***` comments

```
import React from "react";
import "../assets/arrow-up.png";

// *** Reusable function to decide whether we're "at the top" or not
function bodyIsAtTop() {
  return (
    document.body.scrollTop <= 40 &&
    document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 40
  );
}

class TopButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // *** Initial state
    this.state = {
      atTop: bodyIsAtTop()
    };
    // *** No need for the following if you use an arrow function
    // this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  // *** Don't make this an arrow, make it a method
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
  };

  // *** Need to unbind when unmounted
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  };

  handleScroll = () => {
    // *** Update state (possibly; if the flag isn't different, this doesn't do anything)
    this.setState({atTop: bodyIsAtTop()});
  };

  render() {
    // *** Get the flag from state, use it below in style
    const {atTop} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="topbutton_container">
        <button
          style={{ display: atTop ? "none" : "block" }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          className="topbutton_button"
        >
          <img src={require("../assets/arrow-up.png")} />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TopButton;
```

There I've kept your arrow functions for `handleScroll` and `handleClick`. There's an argument for making them methods and using `bind` in the constructor instead, but it's mostly a style thing. (Well...style and it's easier to mock prototype methods for testing, which is a non-style reason for using prototype methods and `bind`.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I made it work in a different way whatsoever. My approach was to **1)** Replace the className by id and thus `document.getElementById("buttonid")`  _buttonid is my ID for button_ But the problem with this approach is that the button would render for the very first time. **2)**In order to remove this inconsistency, i set the `display = "none"` in my `componentDidMount()` method. And it is working fine. Do you see a negative side with this approach?

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul - It's working against the library rather than using it, and it means you can't use more than one copy of the component (unless you take the `id` as a prop). It probably *works*, though.